# How to build a new view explorer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink

I am trying to build my own view explorer in Eclipse, but I can't find an example of one explorer completed built. I would like to show the workspace of eclipse in the new view, and then add a filter to show only the '.launch' extension. Does anybody know if there is any tutorial or example already built?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ProjectExplorer](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/navigator/resources/ProjectExplorer.html) class provided by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: For just filtering workspace contents it is enough to create a filter on the already existing project explorer. No need to implement anything, but you can implement a common navigator content provider to have that filter as pre-existing selection in the filter menu of the project explorer.

Second: Implementing yet another project explorer is really bad, even if it is the most often seen. The project explorer is just an implementation of the so called [common navigator framework](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcnf.htm) and you should [extend that common navigator framework](http://www.modumind.com/2007/04/25/common-navigator-tutori-1-hello-world/). The big advantage of this second approach is that the user of your plugin can use *exactly one* project explorer, which can show contents of different project types correctly in one view.

So if I want to see Java projects (with their package hierarchy) and I want to see your projects, then I can see both logical presentations in one view.